# Making a Form Submit run results on page, instead of refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to figure out how I can make my form submit load the results of the desired field into the existing page instead of refreshing, I have this segment.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="inputState" name="inputState" style="width: 100%">
            <option selected>
                Choose...
            </option>
            <option value="account">
                The Accounts
            </option>
            <option value="cape">
                The Capes
            </option>
        </select>
     </div><input type="submit">
</form>
```

The above code works flawlessly other than the fact that it opens a new url, I am wondering how I can load this php on the same page after submitting the form.

```
print $our_submit = $_POST["inputState"];
```

I've looked over all the posts related to AJAX but for my example, I've not been able to get anything to work.. thanks in advance for help, still new to this.

Comment: Show your PHP code which handles the page submission.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to get response from server and stay on the same page. You can use jQuery $.ajax for example.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Show us what you tried, and give us a proper description of what went wrong with it. The purpose of this site is not to give beginner’s tutorials, so if you are unfamiliar with how AJAX works, you need to go do some reading up on that yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code and remove action name like action=""

```
if(isset($_POST["inputState"])){
 $our_submit = $_POST["inputState"];
 print_r($our_submit);
}
```

Comment: This causes the page to refresh still, though it maintains the existing URL the page is still refreshing, which is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: if you not want to refresh page you need to use ajex

Answer (score 0):

In form action like action="`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`"

```
if(isset($_POST["inputState"])){
 $our_submit = $_POST["inputState"];
 print_r($our_submit);
}
```

Try to submit then you get form data

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to refresh the page after form submission, you needt to send your date with AJAX.

The simple way is using Jquery

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="inputState" name="inputState" style="width: 100%">
                <option selected>
                    Choose...
                </option>
                <option value="account">
                    The Accounts
                </option>
                <option value="cape">
                    The Capes
                </option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <input type="submit" class="send-data">
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.send-data').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $('form').attr('action');
                var data = {
                    'inputState' : $('#inputState').val()
                };

                if (data.inputState != '') {
                    $.post(url, data, function(Response) {
                        // Work if your response here
                        console.log(Response);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['inputState']) && !empty($_POST['inputState'])) {
        echo $_POST['inputState'];
        return true;
    }

    echo 'Please Choose a state ...';
?>
```